# how to detect XMIT FIFO is full on a UART 16550 or higher

Tags: driver, uart

I have read already lot of specs and code about UART, but I cannot find any indication on how to find by software interface if the transmit FIFO is full. There is an interrupt when the FIFO is empty. Then I can write at least N characters, where N is the fifo size. But when I have written these N characters, a number of them have already been sent. So I can in fact write more than N characters, but there is no FIFO full interrupt. The specs says that when the fifo is full indeed the TXREADY pin on the chip is inverted. Is there a way to find this by software ? The Line Status Register bit only says that the fifo is not empty, which does not mean it is full...
Anyone can help ? I want to write characters until the fifo is full...

Comment: We don't have the slightest idea of the environment in which you're working. Is this an embedded device? If so how is the UART connected to the processor? What architecture? Are you using an OS? What programming language? Considering UARTs have been successfully used without overrunning the buffer for decades, I'd say you haven't looked at enough working examples.

Comment: I am testing a UART simulator integrated into a simulation platform. I am writing a test driver in C on bare (simulated) powerpc hardware. I want to test that the hardware does the proper thing. I am writing hundreds of characters on the UART and it should flood the FIFO. How can I detect that the FIFO is full ?

Comment: I forgot to mention. The simulator is supposed to simulate a 16550D UART.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me also that they neglected this, but most people get by with the thing as it is.  The usual way to use it is to get an interrupt, fill the FIFO (normally very fast compared to serial data rate) and then return.

There is a situation where it seems to me that what you are asking for could be nice...if transmitting in a polling mode...you want to send 10 bytes, your polling shows the FIFO is not empty, so you have not way to know if you can send them all or not...either you wait there until it is empty, which sort of defeats the purpose of the FIFO, or you continue polling other stuff until you get back to checking for FIFO empty, and maybe that slows your overall transmission rate. Guess it is not a very usual way to operate, so nobody worries about it.

Answer (score 1):

The 16550D datasheet says the following:

> The transmitter holding register interrupt (02) occurs when the XMIT
>   FIFO is empty; it is cleared as soon as the transmitter holding
>   register is written to (**1 to 16 characters may be written to the XMIT
>   FIFO while servicing this interrupt**) or the IIR is read.

This means that when the Line Status Register register (port base + 5) indicates Transmitter Empty condition (in bit 5), the transmit FIFO is completely empty and you may write up to 16 bytes to the transmitter holding register (port base + 0). It is important not to write more than 16 bytes between occurrences of the transmitter empty bit being set.

If you don't need to write 16 bytes at the point when you received the IRQ (or saw the transmitter register empty bit set, if polling), you can either keep track of how many bytes you wrote since the last transmitter empty state, or, just defer writing further bytes until the next transmitter empty state.